# Checkbox when checked all others uncheck and are uncheckable

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes, labelled MON, TUE, WED, through to SUN.  I want a checkbox that is labelled ALL, that would uncheck and disable the other 7 checkboxes. I'm using JQuery, but I can't find documentation for this particular issue.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="feed-info-input-lbl-set">
    <div class="feed-info-label lbl-company-role">Delivery</div> 
    <div class="checkbox-and-value">
        <div class="feed-info-input input-delivery-day" >SUN
            <br />
            <input id="chk-sun" class="chk-ctrl" type="checkbox" name="delivery-day" value="sunday" />
        </div>
        <div class="feed-info-input input-delivery-day" >MON
            <br />    
        <input id="chk-mon" class="chk-conn" type="checkbox" name="delivery-day" value="monday" />
        </div>
        <div class="feed-info-input input-delivery-day" >TUE
    ...ETC
</div> <!--  End Checkboxes -->
```

Anybody have any information on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Check out jQuery's `.prop` method to set the 'checked' property of the checkboxes

Comment: Bind to the checked event of "ALL" a function that selects and checks/unchecks all the others. Just like that. There's no special function to do this.

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like

```
$("#ALL").change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
 $(":checkbox").not(this).attr("disabled","disabled").removeAttr("checked");
}else{
$(":checkbox").not(this).removeAttr("disabled");
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly simple.  Use jquery selectors to identify your checkboxes (can't get more precise without a code sample) and then call .prop("checked", false) followed by .attr('disabled', 'disabled') on the lot of them.

...if that doesn't solve your problem, perhaps you could be a bit clearer about what you're having difficulty with?